# Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED

Tags: angular, typescript, restful-authentication

I have been developing an angular application with restful API get(). I have got few errors like unauthorization error:401 which has been solved. Now I am getting this error which is kind of straight-forward. I have tried added CORS package as well.

I have been searching for solutions which are in vain. I have re-edited my previous question but seems no response.

```
my-httpservice.service

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from 
'@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class MyHttpserviceService {

constructor(private http:Http) {}

server_grid_Get(){

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var user = "Root";
var pass = "root";

//Use Basic authentication

request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + pass));
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credential','true');

 request.open("GET", "http://192.100.00.000:0000/_db/xxxxx_app/_api/document/wsdl_test/4934434",true);

  return this.http.get("http://192.100.00.000:0000/_db/xxxx_app/_api/document/wsdl_test/4934434").map(response => response.json());


 request.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
    } else {
        console.warn(request.statusText, request.responseText);
    }
  });
  request.send();
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should read again the http guide of angular ( for v5 https://angular.io/guide/http ) before diging further. If you are using angular you should not create mannually your XHRs. Angular will make that for you. After you have proper angular code we will be able to help you far more easily

Comment: @PierreMallet haii..,I will read again. But i have used this code because i am dealing with arangoDBs api. Is it completely wrong ?

Comment: Its wrong to manually create XHR unless you are absolutly sure of what you are doing and that angular cant handle it for you :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#headers)

you should use something like that (angular 4.3+ / Make sure you use HttpClientModule and not old HttpModule)

```
@Injectable()
export class MyHttpserviceService {      
  constructor(private http:HttpClientModule) {}
  private makeMyRequest () {
       return this.http.get("http://192.100.00.000:0000/_db/xxxx_app/_api/document/wsdl_test/4934434", {
            headers: new HttpHeaders()
                .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(user + ':' + pass))
                .set('Content-Type','application/json')
                .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credential','true')
          });
  }
}
```

then in a component

```
<yourservice>.makeMyRequest().subscribe(data => {
     // anything you want
});
```

Comment: this works perfectly..!! thank you so much for saving my day !!

Answer (score 3):

In my case my header had a `\n` char at the end of the auth header value it which caused all the mess

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you handle it?

Comment: Remove the \n at the end of the auth header

Comment: The problem is I want to pass a private key (which contains many `\n`). Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It's been 3 years since I answered here - so can't really recall - try to remove only the last \n char perhaps

Comment: I'll try, thanks :)

Comment: This was the case at us aswell. I wonder how did the linebreak got there in the first place. It seems like it broke overnight.